# Why does wix console gives undefined error?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have set up a GET method API for sending otp to the number entered in form on my wix site.

here is the backend code-----

```
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';
export function OtpVerification(mobile){

const key= 'my_Api_key hidden'
const url= 'https://www.fast2sms.com/dev/bulk?authorization=' + 'key' + '&sender_id=FSTSMS&language=english&route=qt&numbers=' + 'mobile' + '&message=16430&variables={AA}&variables_values=12345';

console.log("url: " + url);
 return fetch(url, {method: 'get'})
 .then(response=> response.json())
}
```

And the front end code for a button click is

```
import {getOtpVerification} from 'backend/otpverify';
$w.onReady(function(){
});

export function button2_click(event,$w) {
getOtpVerification($w("#mobile").value)
.then()
}
```

Console gives error on line `getOtpVerification($w("#mobile").value)`

Error is

> TypeError: (0 , _otpverify.getOtpVerification) is not a function

My coding knowledge is zero. I learned this code from documentation. Any help will be appreciated.